# Math Equation with indent

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I am want to move the all math equation 60pt from left margin using \mathindent. But when equation exceed with text width, that particular equation align with right to left.

See my MWE is below

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{60pt}


\begin{document}

A standard data availability statement has been added to your article, based on the information you gave in your submission. This text cannot be changed unless there is an error. Please remove any other data statement if the information is now duplicated.\vspace*{12pt}

{\noindent\large\textbf{Need to move right to left align}}

\begin{equation}
X^T = \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right), X^S = \left( {S_1^B,S_2^B,\ldots,S_B^B} \right) X^T = \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right).
\end{equation}

A standard data availability statement has been added to your article, based on the information you gave in your submission. This text cannot be changed unless there is an error. Please remove any other data statement if the information is now duplicated.\vspace*{12pt}

{\noindent\large\textbf{Correct One}}

\begin{equation}
X^T = \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right), X^S = \left( {S_1^B,S_2^B,\ldots,S_B^B} \right)
\end{equation}

A standard data availability statement has been added to your article, based on the information you gave in your submission. This text cannot be changed unless there is an error. Please remove any other data statement if the information is now duplicated.\vspace*{12pt}

{\noindent\large\textbf{Need to move slightly left}}

\begin{align}
A_b^s = {F_{\textrm{{sAvg}}}}\left( {{A_b}^\mathrm{avg}} \right) &= \frac{1}{{H \times W}}\sum\limits_{h = 1}^H {\sum\limits_{w = 1}^W {{A_b}^\mathrm{avg}\left( {h,w} \right)}} {A_{h,w,b}}^\mathrm{avg} = {F_{\textrm{{cAvg}}}}\nonumber\\
X^T &= \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right), X^S = \left( {S_1^B,S_2^B,\ldots,S_B^B} \right)
\end{align}


A standard data availability statement has been added to your article, based on the information you gave in your submission. This text cannot be changed unless there is an error. Please remove any other data statement if the information is now duplicated.\vspace*{12pt}

{\noindent\large\textbf{Correct One}}
% \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{align}
A_b^s &= {F_{\textrm{{sAvg}}}}\left( {{A_b}^\mathrm{avg}} \right) = \frac{1}{{H \times W}}\sum\limits_{h = 1}^H {\sum\limits_{w = 1}^W {{A_b}^\mathrm{avg}\left( {h,w} \right)}} {A_{h,w,b}}^\mathrm{avg} \nonumber\\
X^T &= \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right), X^S = \left( {S_1^B,S_2^B,\ldots,S_B^B} \right)
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do all the equations have to be in that exact arrangement? Is breaking them into multiple lines an option?

Comment: @celdor > I need all equations extract(fix in width). breaking in not an option.

Comment: Perhaps changing a font can solve it. Try to add `\usepackage{newtxmath}` after `amsmath`.

Comment: It seems you can even set a new scale as a package option e.g. `\usepackage[scale=0.9]{newtxmath}` (see the [newtx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution: use the `fleqn` environment (from `nccmath`) where necessary:

```
    \documentclass{book}

    \usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
    \setlength{\mathindent}{60pt}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

    \begin{document}

    A standard data availability statement has been added to your article, based on the information you gave in your submission. This text cannot be changed unless there is an error. Please remove any other data statement if the information is now duplicated.\vspace*{12pt}

    {\noindent\large\textbf{Need to move right to left align}}
    \begin{fleqn}%[60pt]
    \begin{equation}
    X^T = \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right), X^S = \left( {S_1^B,S_2^B,\ldots,S_B^B} \right) X^T = \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right).
    \end{equation}
    \end{fleqn}

    A standard data availability statement has been added to your article, based on the information you gave in your submission. This text cannot be changed unless there is an error. Please remove any other data statement if the information is now duplicated.\vspace*{12pt}

    {\noindent\large\textbf{Correct One}}

    \begin{equation}
    X^T = \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right), X^S = \left( {S_1^B,S_2^B,\ldots,S_B^B} \right)
    \end{equation}

    A standard data availability statement has been added to your article, based on the information you gave in your submission. This text cannot be changed unless there is an error. Please remove any other data statement if the information is now duplicated.\vspace*{12pt}

    {\noindent\large\textbf{Need to move slightly left}}
    \begin{fleqn}
    \begin{align}
    A_b^s = {F_{\textrm{{sAvg}}}}\left( {{A_b}^\mathrm{avg}} \right) &= \frac{1}{{H \times W}}\sum\limits_{h = 1}^H {\sum\limits_{w = 1}^W {{A_b}^\mathrm{avg}\left( {h,w} \right)}} {A_{h,w,b}}^\mathrm{avg} = {F_{\textrm{{cAvg}}}}\nonumber\\
    X^T &= \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right), X^S = \left( {S_1^B,S_2^B,\ldots,S_B^B} \right)
    \end{align}
    \end{fleqn}

    A standard data availability statement has been added to your article, based on the information you gave in your submission. This text cannot be changed unless there is an error. Please remove any other data statement if the information is now duplicated.\vspace*{12pt}

    {\noindent\large\textbf{Correct One}}
    \begin{align}
    A_b^s &= {F_{\textrm{{sAvg}}}}\left( {{A_b}^\mathrm{avg}} \right) = \frac{1}{{H \times W}}\sum\limits_{h = 1}^H {\sum\limits_{w = 1}^W {{A_b}^\mathrm{avg}\left( {h,w} \right)}} {A_{h,w,b}}^\mathrm{avg} \nonumber\\
    X^T &= \left({S_1^T,S_2^T,\ldots,S_T^T} \right), X^S = \left( {S_1^B,S_2^B,\ldots,S_B^B} \right)
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

[image]